# Applescript in Photoshop CS6: can't save a JPEG! WHY?

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I wrote a very VERY simple script droplet here. I use it to convert PDFs into a jpg after running an action. I simply drag the PDFs onto the droplet.

When it finishes, no file is saved. Ever. I've tried POSIX, quoted form, saving from a server, saving from my desktop, different syntaxes...nothing works. Photoshop isn't saving the damn file no matter what I do. I even copied the same exact code from the guide and it doesn't effing work.

```
 on open myItems
    repeat with thisItem in myItems
        tell application "System Events"
            set targetFolderPath to path of container of disk item (thisItem as text)
        end tell


        tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
            set display dialogs to never
            open thisItem as PDF with options ¬
                {class:PDF open options, mode:RGB, resolution:180, use antialias:true, crop page:crop box}

            set myDoc to name of current document
            set filePath to targetFolderPath & myDoc & ".jpg"

            do action "MyAction" from "Default"

            save in file filePath as JPEG with options {quality:12}
            close the current document saving no
        end tell
 end open
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
save in file filePath as JPEG with options {class:JPEG save options, quality:12}
```

The given options need to be declared as **JPEG save options**!

Another problem can occur when trying to save transparencies, but I think Photoshop will kick them while saving the image as Jpeg!

Cheers, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: *OMG* I found your error: You don't tell Photoshop to save the document, you just  say **SAVE** without target. Please try `save current document in file filePath as JPEG with options {class:JPEG save options, quality:12}` - Sorry for being blind and pointing to the wrong direction! Michael

Comment: I just discovered that as the problem, then came here to see you'd found out the same thing. You're exactly right: you tell the current document to save -- not the application.